# Occasional memory leak of VC++ console application with system("pause")

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, console-application

OK. So this memory leak occurs randomly. And I tried to reproduce it in a simplified version of my original program. It's a VC++ console application with common header files for MFC.

The following is my memManager class, which originally is a image correction class that manages memory and also processes image.

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

}TPoint;

class memManager
{
public:
    memManager();
    ~memManager();
    void AllocMemory(TPoint **pAddr, int nSize);
    void ReleaseMemory(TPoint **pAddr);
    void ReleaseAllMemory();

    TPoint* ptsPtr;
};

memManager::memManager()
{
    ptsPtr = NULL;
}
memManager::~memManager()
{
    ReleaseAllMemory();
}

void memManager::AllocMemory(TPoint **pAddr, int nSize)
{
    if (*pAddr != NULL)
        return;

    TPoint *pTempAddr;
    pTempAddr = new TPoint[nSize];
    memset(pTempAddr, 0, sizeof(TPoint)*nSize);
    *pAddr = pTempAddr;
    return;
}

void memManager::ReleaseMemory(TPoint **pAddr)
{
    if (*pAddr != NULL)
    {
        delete[] * pAddr;
        *pAddr = NULL;
    }
    return;
}
void memManager::ReleaseAllMemory()
{
    ReleaseMemory(&ptsPtr);
    return;
}
```

And here is the the code in the main function.

```
memManager myMemManager;
myMemManager.AllocMemory(&myMemManager.ptsPtr,5000000);
system("pause");
```

When I debug the program, the console window shows with a prompt "Press any key to continue." And then I close the window by clicking the close button. One out of ten times, the output window of visual studio shows the following:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{83} normal block at 0x000001FC942D9070, 40000000 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete."
The program '[348] testForMemLeak.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

I found it tricky to reproduce the result. Only if I clicked the close button right after the "busy" blue circle disappeared, should I get the memory leak message.

Is it because my memory handling function isn't good enough, or because the console application refused to call the destructor of memManager when I close the console window with bad timing?

Thanks.

Comment: The exit code is more relevant.  0xc000013a says that the program terminated abnormally.  You either typed Ctrl+C or used the console's Close button.  So normal cleanup did not happen, something is bound to leak.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks. You may as well change the comment into an answer. So I'll accept it.

Comment: If you register a console control handler, you can handle Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break however you want. On the other hand, the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` gives your handler 5 seconds to return before Windows terminates the process. That should be enough time to exit gracefully. If the handler returns that it handled the event but without exiting the process, Windows will terminate the process anyway. It can exit clean or dirty, but exit it must.